# Deleted var/log/* and now Ubuntu tries to enter setup on boot

Tags: 18.04, login, log, delete

I deleted by doing `sudo rm -rf var/log/*` to clear some space.

Now when I boot the machine, it enters the Ubuntu setup pages (language, location, new username and password etc). Beyond that, it enters the desktop but I can't access the terminal or Ubuntu configuration, only the top bar which says that the user is 'gnome-initial-setup'. It has connected to my usual Wifi access point though.

I've tried to enter the tty using `alt`+`F2` but it doesn't seem to recognise my old username and password or new one.

Help!

Comment: That doesn't happens by deleting var/log/* ... Please update the question with the EXACT command you run, and the directory you where in.

Comment: That IS exactly what I did. Nonetheless I've updated with the exact command.

Comment: I was in the root directory ```sudo rm-rf var/log/*```

Comment: Are you booting from install media (USB or DVD) instead of version installed on disk ? Normally an installed Ubuntu will never go back to setup  pages.

Comment: No, not booting from installation media. Is it possible it tried to update over Wifi?

Comment: @user14475135 See if what I provided gets it working again. I made the instructions based on my /var/log/ and the files it in that are not backups.

Answer (score 0):

Commands to recreate /var/log (FILES only; no dirs) ...

```
cd /var/log/
sudo touch ubuntu-advantage.log bootstrap.log Xorg.1.log faillog fontconfig.log btmp apport.log lastlog dmesg.0 alternatives.log Xorg.0.log.old gpu-manager-switch.log gpu-manager.log boot.log dmesg Xorg.0.log wtmp dpkg.log kern.log syslog auth.log

sudo chown root:root *.log
sudo chown root:root faillog
sudo chown syslog:adm kern.log 
sudo chown syslog:adm syslog
sudo chown syslog:adm auth.log
sudo chown root:adm dmesg*
sudo chgrp utmp btmp
sudo chgrp utmp wtmp
sudo chgrp adm apport.log
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that I cannot access the terminal or anything useful. I can't log in using TTY because it doesn't recognize my credentials any more and the Gnome desktop says that I'm logged in as 'gnome-initial-setup'

Comment: 2 methods: use a live session. Or use grub rescue.

Comment: OK. Doing that now. Should I expect to see my existing user in the ```passwd``` file from a live session?

Comment: yes BUT you need to be looking at the password file of the partition you -mounted- Not the virtual one from the live session (so it will be in something like `/media/{id}/etc/passwd` )

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that somehow, deleting `/var/log/*` resulted in the user being removed. I used root to recreate the user and associate with original home directory and everything is working fine again.